# Filter Many to Many relation in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this structure of model objects:

Class A:

```
b = models.ManyToManyField("B")
```

Class B:

```
c = models.ForeignKey("C")
d = models.ForeignKey("D")
```

Class C:

```
d = models.ForeignKey("D")
```

This is the query I'm trying to get:
I want to get all the B objects of object A, then in each B object to perform a comparison between the D object and the c.d object.

I know that simply move on the B collection with for loop and make this comparison. 
But I dived on the ManyToMany relation, then I noticed I can do the following:

```
bObjects = A.objects.all().b

q = bObjects.filter(c__d=None)
```

This is working, it gives me all the c objects with `None` d field. But when I try the following :

```
q = bObjects.filter(c__d=d)
```

It gives me d not defined, but d is an object like c in the object B.

What can be the problem? I'll be happy if you suggest further way to do this task.
I generally I'm trying to write my query in a single operation with many to many sub objects and not using loops.

Comment: all this abc is confusing could you not choose better names :D ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `q = bObjects.filter(c_d=d)` //Give me d not defined. but d is an object like c in the object B.

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F
q = bObjects.filter(c__d=F('d'))
```

As for the question from your comment below you can have 1 sql query instead of 100 in those ways:

1) if you can express your selection of A objects in terms of a query (for example a.price<10 and a.weight>20) use this:

```
B.objects.filter(a__price__lt=10, a__weight__gt=20, c__d=F('d'))
```

or this:

```
B.objects.filter(a__in=A.objects.filter(price__lt=10, weight__gt=20), c_d=F('d'))
```

2) if you just have a python list of A objects, use this:

```
B.objects.filter(a__pk__in=[a.pk for a in your_a_list], c__d=F('d'))
```

Comment: Thanks allot, It works. One more question : If I have list of objects of the main object A. Can I do the query you wrote with one line and not iterate over the A list and do the same thing.
Simply I want to save hits to the DB id I have 100 of A then I have to make the query 100 time.

Thanks

Comment: Wasim, add .select_related('a') to the tend of your query

Comment: Thank you very much , it works.
On note : if I write B.objects.filter(a__in=A.objects.filter(price__lt=10, weight__gt=20).query,c_d=F('d')) . It throws an error  SQL Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s).
I looked at the generated SQL , then instead of .query I replaced it with .all and this solved the problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: You could as well remove `.query` and it would work. Updated my answer.